# Ember: Application.hbs not generating in body while building

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have a problem with ember-cli build option.
While running server by `ember s` it's showing normal page with content, styles etc.
But now I want to build this app and put it on my website by ftp so i tried `ember build` which build my project into `/disk` folder but the `index.html` file doesn't contain the stuff from `application.hbs` + no styles from `styles/app.css`.
I'm new to ember. What am I doing wrong? Docs of ember are saying nothing about this.

Comment: Are you *absolutly sure* the content from `/templates/application.hbs` is inserted when you load the page and not later by JS? Try to do `wget http://localhost:4200/`. What is the downloaded content? It should *not* contain the stuff from `/templates/application.hbs` except if you use Fastboot. It is *correct* that it is missing. It gets added by JS *in the browser*.

Answer (score 0):

All of your app is actually pulled in through external assets.

So, looking at your pre-built index.html, you'll see something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>emberclear</title>

    {{content-for "head"}}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{rootURL}}assets/emberclear.css">


    {{content-for "head-footer"}}
  </head>
  <body class='has-navbar-fixed-top'>
    {{content-for "body"}}

    <script src="{{rootURL}}assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="{{rootURL}}assets/emberclear.js"></script>

    {{content-for "body-footer"}}
  </body>
</html>
```

my application is https://emberclear.io, named emberclear, so substitute your app name where applicable.

In the `head`, we see two `link` tags.

- the first `link` is for all the styles that your addons may include (maybe such as material-ui, or bootstrap, or bulma).
- The second `link` is your actual app styles. for me, `emberclear.css` includes everything from `app.css`, and all of its dependencies (I'm actually using scss, so I can include stuff via scss' `@import`).

Down in the `body` we see two `script` tags.

- `vendor.js` will contain ember itself, and any addon dependencies that need to be included at run time, such as ember-paper's library of components.
- `emberclear.js` includes your app -- routes, templates, etc.

This technique is common for all single page apps, and isn't exclusive to ember. anything built with react, or vue, has a similar pattern.

If you're wanting to have html and css be a part of your index.html, fastboot (https://www.ember-fastboot.com/) + prember (pre-rendered ember: https://github.com/ef4/prember ) may be of interest to you.

Hope this helps! :)

If something is wrong, feel free to copy your built index.html from dist (and maybe additional files as well).

Some follow up questions for you, depending on the issues you are running in to:

- Are you getting any errors?
- What happens when you try to open the dist/index.html file locally?
- You're uploading the contents of `dist` to an ftp folder. This in-of-itself is fine, but has the web-sever been told to use that ftp folder for a website?

  - How are you attempting to access the ftp folder via browser?
  - Maybe there is a domain/path we could look at to see additional details?

Comment: Yeah i get what represents what but the main issue is that while running `ember build` it builds it but `{{content for: body}}` is empty, while by running `ember s` it puts there content from `/templates/application.hbs`

Comment: If you disable JavaScript in development, does content for body still get populated?

Comment: are you maybe using fastboot by accident?

Comment: @Lux me or @ilyaBauer?

Comment: @IlyaBauer. If Fastboot is used in the development server this would explain why his content is populated.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using a Fastboot. I'll keep you up with that. Going to do some tests tomorrow.